# use regex to map TY_111.22-L007-C010 from a text

Tags: java, regex

I want to get TY_111.22-L007-C010,Tzo11-L010-C100 and Tff-L010-C110 from this string with regex

```
"12.5*MAX(\"TY_111.22-L007-C010\";\"Tzo11-L010-C100\";\"Tff-L010-C110\")
```

I tested this `T.*-L\d*-C\d*` but it don't give the result I want :

My code java for test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "T.*-L\\d*-C\\d*";
final String string = "\"12.5*MAX(\\\"TY_111.22-L007-C010\\\";\\\"Tzo11-L010-C100\\\";\\\"Tff-L010-C110\\\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex [`T.*?\-L\d*?\-C\d*`](https://regex101.com/r/AJ2itV/1)

```
final String regex = "T.*?\\-L\\d*?\\-C\\d*";
```

Note: you need to escape the hyphens `\-` and use non-greedy quantifier `.*?` instead of `.*`, also you can use only `matcher.group()` instead of `matcher.group(0)`, in your regex you don't have any groups, so the `0` is useless.

---

Outputs

```
Full match: TC_24.00-L010-C090
Full match: TC_24.00-L010-C100
Full match: TC_24.00-L010-C110
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a verbose regex pattern matcher when you can handle the problem with one line of code:

```java
String input = "12.5*MAX(\"Txxxx-L007-C010\";\"Txxxx-L010-C100\";\"Txxxx-L010-C110\")";
String[] matches = input.replaceAll("^.*?\"|\"[^\"]*$", "")
                        .split("\";\"");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matches));
```

This prints:

```
[Txxxx-L007-C010, Txxxx-L010-C100, Txxxx-L010-C110]
```

OK...I used *three* lines of code, but the first and third are just for setting up the data and printing it.